# threadpool settings doesn't support in elasticsearch 6.2.1

Tags: elasticsearch

i'm unable to set below perporties through elasticsearch.yml file in elasticsearch 6.2.1, but these were working earlier in elasticsearch 2.x

```
threadpool.bulk.type: fixed

threadpool.bulk.size: 16 

threadpool.bulk.queue_size: 5000
```

getting below error-

```
[2018-02-19T14:27:05,861][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] []
 uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
: unknown setting [threadpool.bulk.queue_size] did you mean any of [thread_pool.
bulk.queue_size, thread_pool.get.queue_size, thread_pool.index.queue_size, threa
d_pool.search.queue_size, thread_pool.bulk.size, thread_pool.listener.queue_size
]?
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:125
) ~[elasticsearch-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
```

Please help me to fix this , Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you give a try  with thread_pool.bulk.queue_size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2.x it was threadpool

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-threadpool.html

but in latest version it is changed as thead_pool

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html

Comment: Thanks for your remark , but with this change i'm able to set only this "thread_pool.bulk.queue_size", remaining two properties "thread_pool.bulk.type, thread_pool.bulk.size" i'm unable to set, could you pls help me in this